# How to check timer expiry in timerfd_create

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to create a timer using `timerfd_create`, but i don't know how to check for the expiry.

Can someone please help me with an easy example?

I know how to create and populate using the `settime` as you can see from my earlier timer questions, but how to check the expiry of `timerfd_create`? I know it notifies via file descriptor of it's expiry. But how to check it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` or `epoll` to monitor the file descriptor. Here's an example:

```
struct epoll_event event;
efd = epoll_create(2);

event.data.fd = timer_fd;
event.events = EPOLLIN;
epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timer_fd, &event);

while (1) {
    struct epoll_event revent;
    epoll_wait(efd, &revent, 1, -1);
    /* revent can now be used */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you pls tell me how you know the expiry here?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I don't understand what you mean. You know it expired because the `epoll` fired. What do you need more ?